# Scala Argument Types of Anonymous Function in Overload

Tags: scala, anonymous-function, overloading

There are quite a few questions about this error message on SO, but none of them seem to be about this issue.

```
The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5)
```

The offending block of code is attempting to emulate Ruby's block functionality, with the added benefit that an argument can be pattern matched in the process.

```
object Block {
  def apply(f: => Unit) = apply((_: String) => f)
  def apply(f: String => Unit) = ???
}
def example() = {
  Block { // Error!
    case "A" => println("First letter of the alphabet")
    case _   => println("Not the first letter of the alphabet")
  }
}
```

Even though, one line down, Scala can clearly see that I'm matching against a string, it can't infer the argument type.

Answer (score 1):

The trouble here is that there are two `apply` methods. If there was only one:

```
object Block {
  def apply(f: String => Bool) = ???
}
```

Then everything would work fine, as Scala would see the application and immediately understand the required type of the anonymous function. However, when there are two or more different methods:

```
object Block {
  def apply(f: => Bool) = apply((_: String) => f)
  def apply(f: String => Bool) = ???
}
```

Scala cannot deduce the type of the argument from the application of `apply`, and it cannot deduce which application of `apply` to use from the type of the argument, so it gets caught in a loop. The simplest solution, it seems, is to simply rename one of the methods.

```
object Block {
  def apply(f: => Unit) = apply((_: String) => f)
  def branchOff(f: String => Unit) = ???
}
```

It's not much more difficult to call now.

```
Block { println("This is a regular application.") }
Block.branchOff {
  case "A" => println("A is for aardvark")
  case "B" => println("B is for beaver")
  case _   => println("Huh?")
}
```

And you don't have to specify any type arguments, or any explicit arguments at all for that matter.

More details on this in a thread over on GitHub: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxScala/issues/160.

Answer (score 1):

If you really like the idea of having two different `apply()` methods then you have to offer some help to the inference engine.

```
def example() = {
  Block{s:String => s match {
    case "A" => println("First letter of the alphabet")
    case _   => println("Not the first letter of the alphabet")
  }}
}
```